# WS.SaveAs is to slow if programm is run by Button-Click

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating .CSV-Files for every worksheet in a workbook with an Excel macro. This all works fine if I run the macro by clicking on Macro in the Developer-Tab and run the macro from there.

If I run the macro from a Form-Button inside the Excel-File, it creates a CSV-File for every Worksheet, but with no content.

Here the VBA-Code:

```
    'This method generates CSV-Files for every Worksheet in a Workbook.
    Sub BtnGenerateCSV_click()

    Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SaveToDirectory As String
    Dim intResult As Integer

    On Error GoTo Heaven

    'Disable all for my script unnecessary things.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Opens a file dialog for choosing the destination folder
    intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show

    If intResult <> 0 Then
    'If a selection was made, the selected path is saved into this variable.
    SaveToDirectory = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name = "Wegleitung" Or startsWith(WS.Name, "Hilfstabelle") Then
        'Do Nothing because these Worksheets are just helping tables and not used data.
        Else
            'Saving the Worksheet as a CSV to the chosen path with the name of the Worksheet.
            WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name, xlCSV
        End If

    Next
    ThisWorkbook.Close
    End If

'Enable all these for my script unnecessary things.
Finally:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Error-Handling
Heaven:
    MsgBox "Couldn't save all sheets to CSV." & vbCrLf & _
        "Source: " & Err.Source & " " & vbCrLf & _
        "Number: " & Err.Number & " " & vbCrLf & _
        "Description: " & Err.Description & " " & vbCrLf
End Sub

'This mmethod checks if a String starts with a specific other String.
Public Function startsWith(str As String, prefix As String) As Boolean
    startsWith = Left(str, Len(prefix)) = prefix
End Function
```

I'm not sure about the real reason of the problem but I thought that it would have to do something with this method SaveAs which is too slow to finish it's tasks and gets interrupted by something. I think this because it has enough time to create the files but not to fill them with the data.

I tried to use the method DoEvents after the SaveAs but this didn't work. Also I tried to disable the Events on the Application which, I thought, would be also a possible reason for interrupt the SaveAs-Method.

Finally I read a lot of questions on Stackoverflow addressing the task of creating CSV-Files out of a Excel-File but I did not find an answer to this problem. I hope this is not a duplicate, but please correct me if it is.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things.

1. Instead of `startsWith(WS.Name, "Hilfstabelle")` you can actually use `Like` operator. For example `Like "Hilfstabelle*"`. That ways you do not need to use a separate function.
2. You need to exit the code before `Heaven:`
3. Try this code mentioned below. I have not tested it. Let me know if you face any problems.

**Code:**

```
Sub BtnGenerateCSV_click()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim SaveToDirectory As String
    Dim intResult As Integer

    On Error GoTo Heaven

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show

    If intResult <> 0 Then
        SaveToDirectory = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"

        For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If WS.Name = "Wegleitung" Or WS.Name Like "Hilfstabelle*" Then
            Else
                WS.Copy
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
                ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If
        Next
    End If
Finally:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    MsgBox "Done"
    Exit Sub
Heaven:
    MsgBox "Couldn't save all sheets to CSV." & vbCrLf & _
    "Source: " & Err.Source & " " & vbCrLf & _
    "Number: " & Err.Number & " " & vbCrLf & _
    "Description: " & Err.Description & " " & vbCrLf

    Resume Finally
End Sub
```

Comment: But I have still some Questions: When I open the CSV-Files in an Excel-File there is still a link to the Macro in the first File. Is there a way to get rid of that ? also Excel tells me that this is a SLYK-File and is possibly dangerous but it seems that this comes from the fact that in the first Cell of the File it's written "ID" which seems to be a problem of [Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/de-ch/kb/323626). 

And at the End, just to understand, you take the Worksheet, copy it to a new Workbook which then is Active, then you save it and Close it without changes ?

Comment: 1. Csv files are simply text files. How will they have link to a macro? 2. Did adding the apostrophe help? 3. Yes, I took the worksheet, copied it and then closed it without saving becuase `.Save As` alrady saved it ;)

Comment: 1. It was visible because i had the other file opened in the background. 
2. I took the option to write it in lower case letters. instead of the apostroph because i want to map it to a DB-Model by reflection but this is another story.
3. Shure I understand now though i don't really understand why it did not work when i saved the Worksheets alone. Maybe it had to save a Workbook around the sheet and this took the time it hadn't if not run out of the developertab anyways thank you very much for the time spent!